# How can I task schedule a .py file in every hour in a Debian (linux system)?

Tags: python, linux, debian, scheduled-tasks

I want to run my program in every 3 hours, what i have to download or how can i do this in a Debian system? (In windows it is very clear and easy, but in Linux system I dont know the solution yet how to run a program periodic.)

Comment: Couldn't you Google this? In any case, this is not a programming question.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems you generally use cronjobs for scheduled tasks.
Check out crontab on your command line.

You can add scripts to be called and how often they should be called.

On Wikipedia you can find the structure of a crontab:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Yes, i found this crontab solution, but in this way i have to write 8 command line if i want to do it in every 3 hours? Or in this way it is correct? 0 */3 * * * /usr/src/Python-2.7.13/my_python_file.py

Comment: Ups I am sorry. Ubuntuusers is a German site. I'll change the link to something in English. But yes, your cron seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a bash file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /path/to/your/pythonfile.py
```

Then add it to your crontab:

```
* 3 * * * /path/to/your/bashfile/file.sh
```

Comment: I created a bash file, with your code (with vi editor).
After I added the suggested line to my crontab -e file, but nothing is happening.

Comment: @Mr.D What happens when you run the bash file manually? ./yourbashfile.sh

Comment: It looks like it is started (flashing once) and I can write a new command (but the script not started)

Comment: I think it is started? Does ps -aux | grep  python
output your program? Or is there any way you can check if it is running?

Comment: It's sure it is not started (i checked my sql file, because this script modify it, so i can check it easily). If I write you code i get this: web 7103 0.0. 0.0 12796 940pts/1 S+ 13:36 0:00 grep python

Comment: How do you normally run the pytnon file from terminal? 
Put that command in yourbashfile.sh below the #!/bin/bash

Comment: I tried with anoter .py file, it is working with bash.
I modified this part * * * * * (to start it every minute in the crontab -e file), but it isnt running

Comment: First make sure cron is running: pgrep cron
this should output a PID number.
Make sure your file is executable: chmod +x yourfile.sh
When adding to crontab -e are you running it as root?
Try adding bash to the command line like this:
* 3 * * *        root  /bin/bash /path/to/your/bashfile/file.sh

Comment: It is executable, i runned as root. Why i need this part: root /bin/bash?
Btw still not working :(

Comment: Hmm sometimes your bash path could be wrong, typing it directly into cron would ignore that.
Can you try adding the script manually to /etc/crontab ?

Comment: Sorry me too - the way I described is how I run cron on 10+ servers